# How to run "package" before 'test"

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala compiler project. Some of the test cases depend on the generated jar file.
Therefore, I always manually run the "package" task before running the "test" task.

How can I add a SBT task that will do the job of "test" but will depend on "package"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**sbt 0.12:**

Add the following to your project settings:

```
(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (Keys.`package` in Compile)
```

This changes the test task for your project. But you can also define your own task:

```
val myTestTask = TaskKey[Unit]("my-test-task", "runs package and then test")
```

And then add this to your project settings:

```
myTestTask <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (Keys.`package` in Compile)
```

**sbt 0.13:**

Add the following to your project settings:

```
(test in Test) := {
  (Keys.`package` in Compile).value
  (test in Test).value
}
```

This changes the test task for your project. But you can also define your own task:

```
val myTestTask = taskKey[Unit]("runs package and then test")
```

And then add this to your project settings:

```
myTestTask := {
  (Keys.`package` in Compile).value
  (test in Test).value
}
```

Comment: I am getting following error `build.sbt:21: error: eof expected but 'package' found.`


`(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn package`

Comment: I had to change it to `(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (Keys.\`package\` in Compile)`. Is this the usual way, or something peculiar to my setup? Note that omitting `Keys` gives me error ` reference to package is ambiguous. it is imported twice in the same scope, import Keys._ and import sbt._`

Comment: @dips It's an unfortunate conflict with Scala's `package` keyword.

Comment: I changed my answer so it compiles.

Comment: How would I do this in sbt 0.13 syntax (avoiding `<<=`)?

Comment: @SetTisue: Added a section for sbt 0.13.